# How to set id dynamically in ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to load multiple answers when user click a question.There are multiple questions and each has multiple answers.but when i click second question,the answers of first question are also changing.
I have assigned div id dynamically from my controller in ng-repeat,but when i load data into the div,it always loading data into the first question answers div.div ids are unique in ng-repeat but answers of every question are displaying in all divs.

Comment: Can you please show an example of your code? it is more easy to give an answert his way

Comment: more code is required

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that you are using the same ng-model for both questions. If you link some of your code I could better examine it.

Comment: <a href="javascript: void 0;" ng-attr-id="{{question.qid}}"         data-ng-click='getAnswers(this.question);'         
onclick="$('#answer'+this.id).toggle();" >View Answer</a>

<!-- {{question.qid for questions if qid 1 answer would be answer1}}-->

<div ng-attr-id="answer{{question.qid}}">  

<!-- getAnswers(this.question) will fetch mutliple answers into 'answers' scope variable for 
specific question -->

 <div ng-repeat='answer in answers' >
  <p  ng-bind-html='answer.aDescription'></p>         
 </div>
</div>

but it loads all divs with answers of question which i clicked last.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#QuestionID').find('#answerId');
```

select answer id inside particular question instead of directly taking

```
$('#answerId')
```